# Bittorrent PIECE message not received

Tags: udp, bittorrent, utorrent

Basically i get messages like Choke, Unchoke, Have and Bitfield, but i don't receive any of the PIECE messages, why could it be so?

I saw some old unanswered question also, but it didn't help. [BitTorrent protocol implementation: Not receiving "Piece" messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668659/bittorrent-protocol-implementation-not-receiving-piece-messages)

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for that. Most likely:

- Peer should know your state, so make sure you send "Interested", "Not interested", "Choked", "Unchoked" messages. Similarly, you should keep track peer state.
- You are not interested in a peer or peer choking you or both. You can only request a piece when you interested in a peer and peer not choking you. Otherwise peer should ignore your request.
- Peer do not have a piece you requested. In this case peer should ignore request as well.

This is all from [bittorrent specification](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification). Here is part of log that demonstrates required steps to get the first piece:

```
Openning a new session between peers.
Connected to <peer addr>
Handshaked with BitTorrent protocol uTorrent version 2040
Received message: Bitfield 
Update 'peer have' bitfield.
Received message: Have 572
Mark piece 572 as available.
...
... here we receive many Have messages, I skip them
...
Sending message: Interested
Received message: Unchoke
Sending message: Request { piece index = 0, block offset = 0, block length = 16384 }
Received message: Piece { piece index = 0, block offset = 0, block length = 16384 }
...
```

As you can see uTorrent answered with Piece message.

However, in this scenario we've been lucky: peer not always unchoke us since it have limited number of so-called "unchoke slots". So one tip here: use swarm with small ratio of leecher count to seeder count. This should make debugging easier because peer unchoke us more likely.